# Transferring a Google spreadsheet to a Google document

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Help me change the script so that the table from Google Sheets transfers the table to Google Docs only those rows and columns where column G has the value true?
And how can you put the table in the right place?
And how can I put the table in the right place (%table% in the template file)?

[template](https://docs.google.com/document/d/183tq6LvgBhzfbWUpNCWAV0X6Tn49yJ1KGuwKTfiSQJs/edit)

[table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-pbr2EGu66D4h_nboARXdA83xeZO_4vkuFq5qoJBuZ4/edit?pli=1#gid=1931891843)

```
function actGeneration() {
  // Перенос данных
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("183tq6LvgBhzfbWUpNCWAV0X6Tn49yJ1KGuwKTfiSQJs"); //шаблон
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1AgokTJRgvuMdVO_X3sO-S22Nvp5s0i2U"); // директория новых актов
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder); // копия шаблона
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId()); // открываем созданную копию
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody(); // тело(текст) файла копии
    
  // Фиксированные позиции
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); //получаем текст с открытого окна таблицы
  
  var space = Array()
  space[0] = list.getRange(6, 9).getValue(); // дата
  space[1] = list.getRange(2, 9).getValue(); // номер договора
  space[2] = list.getRange(4, 9).getValue(); // имя заказчика
  space[3] = list.getRange(3, 9).getValue(); // адресс заказчика
  space[4] = list.getRange(5, 9).getValue(); // цена заказа
  space[5] = list.getRange(6, 9).getValue(); // дата договора
  space[6] = list.getRange(5, 10).getValue(); // цена прописью
  
  body.replaceText("%дата%", space[0]);
  body.replaceText("%номер%", space[1]);
  body.replaceText("%заказчик%", space[2]);
  body.replaceText("%адрес%", space[3]);
  body.replaceText("%стоимость%", space[4]);
  body.replaceText("%дата.договора%", space[5]);
  body.replaceText("%пропись%", space[6]);

  // Перенос таблицы
  var sheet = list;
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 64, 6).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var backgroundColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var styles = range.getTextStyles();
  var aligns = range.getHorizontalAlignments()

  var colWidth = [];  // Added
  for (var col = 1; col <= 6; col++) {  // Added
    colWidth.push(sheet.getColumnWidth(col) * 3 / 4);
  }

  // Position to paste data in Google Docs
  var table = body.appendTable(values);
  table.setBorderWidth(1);

  colWidth.forEach(function(e, i) {table.setColumnWidth(i, e)});  // Added

  for (var i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < table.getRow(i).getNumCells(); j++) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = backgroundColors[i][j];
        obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = styles[i][j].getFontSize();
        obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = aligns[i][j];
        if (styles[i][j].isBold()) {
          obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
        }
        table.getRow(i).getCell(j).setAttributes(obj);
    }
  }
  
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
}
```

We managed to move the table, but not as expected.

Comment: `.getActiveSheet()` There are three sheets in your spreadsheet; which one do you use as the "active sheet"?

Comment: `We managed to move the table, but not as expected.` Would you please edit your question to show the actual (unexpected) result and also the expected result.

Comment: Cell F60 on "Лист2 (копия)" `=SUM(F59,F52,F43,F37,F30,F21,F12,F9)`; these cells are "ИТОГО" (Total) values within the sheet. Cell F60 is checked "true" so it will carry through to the "Table". BUT... many of the "ИТОГО" (Total) lines are NOT checked, so they won't be carried forward to the "Table". This creates a potential problem as to whether Cell F60 will produce a reliable result when it is copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to the question:

- `only those table rows where column G has the value = true`
- `put the table in the right place (%table% in the template file)`

The answer consists of two scripts:

- **`buildMergeTable()`**

  - creates a new "Merge Table" that can be used for the Document merge
  - "unchecked" rows are deleted
  - "Total" formula has been updated
- **`mergeAndInsertTable()`** - based on the OP's code

  - uses the "Merge Table" for inserting the "Table"
  - inserts the "Table" at `%table%`
  - deletes `%table%` afterwards

The scripts must be run in sequence:

1. `buildMergeTable()`
2. `mergeAndInsertTable()`

- The scripts *can* be combined but I have separated them so that the purpose and process of each script is more clear.

---

**only rows where value = true - function `buildTable()`**

The main steps are:

- copy the original sheet = "Лист2 (копия)"

  - name the copy = "MergeTable""
- loop Column G  === true

  - maintain a rowCounter to keep track of the actual row
  - if true, then increment the rowCounter
  - if not true, then delete the row
- update the "Total" formula

  - deleting rows will corrupt the formula:

    - BEFORE: `=SUM(F59,F52,F43,F37,F30,F21,F12,F9)`
    - AFTER: `=SUM(#REF!,#REF!,#REF!,#REF!,F7,#REF!,#REF!,F4)`
  - use `replaceAll('#REF!,', '')`
  - update the revised formula: `setFormula(newFormula)`

**put the table in the right place (%table%)**

- identify the index for the placeholder

  - `var tablePlaceHolder= body.findText("%table%")`
  - `var element=tablePlaceHolder.getElement()`
  - `var childIndex= body.getChildIndex(element.getParent())`
- delete the placeholder

  - `body.getChild(childIndex).asText().setText('')`
- insert the table at the index

  - `var table = body.insertTable(childIndex,values)`

---

```
function buildMergeTable() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var originalSheetName = "Лист2 (копия)"
  var originalSheet = ss.getSheetByName(originalSheetName);

  // Copy the original sheet
    var targetSheetName = "MergeTable"
    originalSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(targetSheetName);
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName)

  // delete the rows that aren't checked
    var numRows = 64 // fixed
    var lastCol=7 // column G
    var range = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,lastCol)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range = "+range.getA1Notation())
    var values = range.getValues()

    // make a counter for the row number
    let rowCounter = 1
    for (i=0;i<numRows;i++){
      if (values[i][(lastCol-2)] === true){ // zero-based tests column G
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: TRUE i="+i)
        rowCounter++
      }
      else{
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: FALSE, so delete row: i="+i+", row = "+rowCounter)
        targetSheet.deleteRow(rowCounter); // NOT zero-based
      }
    }

  // update the Total cell
    // get the last row and the cell reference
    var bVals = targetSheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
    var bLast = bVals.filter(String).length;
    var totalCellRange = targetSheet.getRange(bLast,6)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the Total cell range = "+totalCellRange.getA1Notation())    

    // get the formula
    var totalCellFormula = totalCellRange.getFormula()
    // remove #REF! from formula
    var newFormula = totalCellFormula.replaceAll('#REF!,', '')

    // update formula 
    totalCellRange.setFormula(newFormula)
}


function mergeAndInsertTable() {
  // Перенос данных
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1fM6_GfqI5_pze8W_aHWqVSTKSTeU_SHHTB020lgxf9w"); //шаблон
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1hhMDnlMzm2B7rzp3Qnehx8sa_gM2B5Yy"); // директория новых актов
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder); // копия шаблона
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId()); // открываем созданную копию
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody(); // тело(текст) файла копии
    
  // Фиксированные позиции
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var mergeSheetName = "Лист1"
  var list = ss.getSheetByName(mergeSheetName) //получаем текст с открытого окна таблицы
   
  var space = Array()

  space[0] = list.getRange(6, 9).getValue(); // дата// date
  space[1] = list.getRange(2, 9).getValue(); //номер договора // contract number
  space[2] = list.getRange(4, 9).getValue(); // имя заказчика // customer name
  space[3] = list.getRange(3, 9).getValue(); // адресс заказчика // customer address
  space[4] = list.getRange(5, 9).getValue(); // цена заказа // order price
  space[5] = list.getRange(6, 9).getValue(); // дата договора// contract date
  space[6] = list.getRange(5, 10).getValue(); // цена прописью // price in writing
  // Logger.log("DEBUG:\nDate:"+space[0]+" ("+list.getRange(6, 9).getA1Notation()+")\nContract#:"+space[1]+" ("+list.getRange(2, 9).getA1Notation()+")\nCustomer:"+space[2]+" ("+list.getRange(4, 9).getA1Notation()+")\nCustomer address:"+space[3]+" ("+list.getRange(3, 9).getA1Notation()+")\nOrder price:"+space[4]+" ("+list.getRange(5, 9).getA1Notation()+")\nContract Date:"+space[5]+" ("+list.getRange(6, 9).getA1Notation()+")\nWritten price:"+space[6]+" ("+list.getRange(5, 10).getA1Notation()+")")
  //return
  body.replaceText("%дата%", space[0]);
  body.replaceText("%номер%", space[1]);
  body.replaceText("%заказчик%", space[2]);
  body.replaceText("%адрес%", space[3]);
  body.replaceText("%стоимость%", space[4]);
  body.replaceText("%дата.договора%", space[5]);
  body.replaceText("%пропись%", space[6]);

  // Перенос таблицы
  
  // Get Google Sheet data
  var tableSheetName = "MergeTable"
  var tableSheet = ss.getSheetByName(tableSheetName)

  // get the last row and the cell reference
  var bVals = tableSheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
  var bLast = bVals.filter(String).length;
  var range = tableSheet.getRange(1, 1, bLast, 6).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
    
  var values = range.getValues();
  var backgroundColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var styles = range.getTextStyles();
  var aligns = range.getHorizontalAlignments()

  var colWidth = [];  // Added
  for (var col = 1; col <= 6; col++) {  // Added
    colWidth.push(tableSheet.getColumnWidth(col) * 3 / 4);
  }
  // Logger.log(colWidth)


  // Position to paste data in Google Docs

  var tablePlaceHolder= body.findText("%table%")
  var element=tablePlaceHolder.getElement()
  var childIndex= body.getChildIndex(element.getParent())
  // delete the table placeholder
  body.getChild(childIndex).asText().setText('')
  var table = body.insertTable(childIndex,values)
  table.setBorderWidth(1);
  colWidth.forEach(function(e, i) {table.setColumnWidth(i, e)});  // Added

  for (var i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < table.getRow(i).getNumCells(); j++) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = backgroundColors[i][j];
        obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = styles[i][j].getFontSize();
        obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = aligns[i][j];
        if (styles[i][j].isBold()) {
          obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
        }
        table.getRow(i).getCell(j).setAttributes(obj);
    }
  }
  
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
}
```

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]

---

Comment: Thank you very much, it's just super!